# Charged particles physics simulation

Tags: gratis, open-source, simulation, scientific-computing

I am looking for a open-source, or anyway free software, that can simulate all possible interactions within charged particles. For example, I want to simulate radiation reaction on electrons and their response to em waves generated by other electrons.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [pyparticles](http://pyparticles.wordpress.com/introduction/) running under [python](http://python.org).

There isn't an example but forces can include electromagnetic as well as gravitation, etc.

- Free & Open Source
- Output can be to pyplot or OpenGL.

[image]
<sup>(Click image for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

GEANT from CERN. It is used in basic research, as well as in applied reserach, for example with radiation oncology machines.

http://geant4.cern.ch/